# Unable to deserialize the JSON result in C#. Input string is not in a correct format error

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a json output to a C# object.
JSON result:

```
{"order":{"commission":3.490000,"cost":4.490000,"duration":"day","extended_hours
":false,"fees":0.000000,"class":"equity","price":1.000000,"quantity":1.000000,"r
equest_date":"2013-11-26T09:43:17.118Z","result":true,"side":"buy","status":"ok"
,"symbol":"DIS","type":"limit"}}
```

My derived class from JSON:

```
    public class Rootobject
{
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public float commission { get; set; }
    public float cost { get; set; }
    public string duration { get; set; }
    public bool extended_hours { get; set; }
    public int fees { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime request_date { get; set; }
    public bool result { get; set; }
    public string side { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Code used to deserialize (JSON.NET from Newtonsoft) :

```
 Rootobject ord = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(responsebody);
```

I am getting the following error.

```
 Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.Int32Parse(Char[] chars, Int32 start, Int32 length)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsInt32Internal()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsInt32()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(Jso
nReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
```

I have tried saving the deserialized result to a "dynamic" object which works fine. But I do not want to use the dynamic object for mapping the fields.

Please advice.

Note: Also the 3rd party API is sending a field called "class". How do I call this as I get compile-time error when I try to directly call the field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the `fees` property in the `Order` class defined as an `int` but in the JSon text it is `0.00000`, i.e. a `float` or `double`. I think you may need to make the `fees` property into a `float` in order to parse it properly. Looks the same for the `price` and `quantity` properties too.

Comment: How DUMB am I.. was trying to fix too many things :-(. Thanks a **TONN ** Jack. Thanks Again!!!

Comment: Also How can I call the field "class" in order to assign it to the internal field?

Comment: if you look at the JSON result, the API is returning a field called "class". Now when I try to read the same (code below), then I get a compile-error as "class" is a keyword. Console.WriteLine("Order Class : Class: {0}", ord.Order.class);

Comment: One solution immediately springs to mind which neatly avoids having to do some Json serializer foo is to change the name of the `class` in the json text to something that doesn't clash with a reserved word like `root`. I'm sure there is a better way, but saves getting stuck on it and you can always fix it later. You could use a reg expression for that.

Comment: Thank You again Jack. I shall use the **_class** that I renamed. Saved my day. Thank You!!!