# How to create objects of JSON text in c#

Tags: c#, json

Hi I am working on web API and getting the result on `StreamReader`. I want to convert these  `StreamReader` to `JSON` I am using the Following code :

```
 var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                MyObject myojb = (MyObject)js.Deserialize(objText, typeof(MyObject));

                // Response.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
```

And the actual Model schema is something like that

```
{
  "id": "",
  "description": "",
  "added_date": "",
  "media_type": "",
  "contributor": {
    "id": ""
  },
  "aspect": 0,
  "image_type": "",
  "is_editorial": false,
  "is_adult": false,
  "is_illustration": false,
  "has_model_release": false,
  "has_property_release": false,
  "releases": [
    ""
  ],
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": "",
      "name": ""
    }
  ],
  "keywords": [
    ""
  ],
  "assets": {
    "small_jpg": {
      "height": 0,
      "width": 0,
      "file_size": 0,
      "display_name": "",
      "dpi": 0,
      "format": "",
      "is_licensable": false
    },
    "medium_jpg": {
      "height": 0,
      "width": 0,
      "file_size": 0,
      "display_name": "",
      "dpi": 0,
      "format": "",
      "is_licensable": false
    },
    "huge_jpg": {
      "height": 0,
      "width": 0,
      "file_size": 0,
      "display_name": "",
      "dpi": 0,
      "format": "",
      "is_licensable": false
    },
    "supersize_jpg": {
      "height": 0,
      "width": 0,
      "file_size": 0,
      "display_name": "",
      "dpi": 0,
      "format": "",
      "is_licensable": false
    },
    "huge_tiff": {
      "height": 0,
      "width": 0,
      "file_size": 0,
      "display_name": "",
      "dpi": 0,
      "format": "",
      "is_licensable": false
    },
    "supersize_tiff": {
      "height": 0,
      "width": 0,
      "file_size": 0,
      "display_name": "",
      "dpi": 0,
      "format": "",
      "is_licensable": false
    },
    "vector_eps": {
      "height": 0,
      "width": 0,
      "file_size": 0,
      "display_name": "",
      "dpi": 0,
      "format": "",
      "is_licensable": false
    },
    "small_thumb": {
      "url": "",
      "height": 0,
      "width": 0
    },
    "large_thumb": {
      "url": "",
      "height": 0,
      "width": 0
    },
    "preview": {
      "url": "",
      "height": 0,
      "width": 0
    },
    "preview_1000": {
      "url": "",
      "height": 0,
      "width": 0
    }
  },
  "models": [
    {
      "id": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

And model is something like this

```
Image {
id (string),
description (string, optional),
added_date (string, optional),
media_type (string),
contributor (Contributor),
aspect (number, optional),
image_type (string, optional),
is_editorial (boolean, optional),
is_adult (boolean, optional),
is_illustration (boolean, optional),
has_model_release (boolean, optional),
has_property_release (boolean, optional),
releases (array[string], optional),
categories (array[Category], optional),
keywords (array[string], optional),
assets (ImageAssets, optional),
models (array[Model], optional)
}
Contributor {
id (string)
}
Category {
id (string, optional),
name (string, optional)
}
ImageAssets {
small_jpg (ImageSizeDetails, optional),
medium_jpg (ImageSizeDetails, optional),
huge_jpg (ImageSizeDetails, optional),
supersize_jpg (ImageSizeDetails, optional),
huge_tiff (ImageSizeDetails, optional),
supersize_tiff (ImageSizeDetails, optional),
vector_eps (ImageSizeDetails, optional),
small_thumb (Thumbnail, optional),
large_thumb (Thumbnail, optional),
preview (Thumbnail, optional),
preview_1000 (Thumbnail, optional)
}
ImageSizeDetails {
height (integer, optional),
width (integer, optional),
file_size (integer, optional),
display_name (string, optional),
dpi (integer, optional),
format (string, optional),
is_licensable (boolean, optional)
}
Thumbnail {
url (string),
height (integer),
width (integer)
}
Model {
id (string)
}
```

But i have no idea how do I create the Objects to get the `JSON` result.I am trying with the `Myobject` class but getting the error:

> Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

Please help how do i get the `JSON` result.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post dump from your *reader* stream? Maybe it is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can use [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for parsing the json result:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(data);
```

With this approach you don't need to fully deserialize the JSON object

**Updated**:

```
var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(objText);
```

**PS**: I used [Paste JSON as Classes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc.aspx) in Visual Studio for generating the models, Or you can use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) for creating the classes.

Comment: @Gitz that's the JSON data as a string.

Comment: where do i put this line ?? Can you please explain ?

Comment: I think you should add "objText" as data.

Comment: var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(objText);

Comment: I Am using `using Newtonsoft.Json;` but `Rootobject` is not found @Sirwan Afifi

Comment: First of all you should install json.net `code`Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`code`. and yes you should pass the `objText` as its parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the Convertor it is nice and I have put the objects also but getting the error "Input string was not in a correct format."

Answer (score 0):

Using `json2csharp` you can create model class from json text.I copied your json text and what i got as output is below class.

```
public class Contributor
{
   public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
public string id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
}

public class SmallJpg
{
public int height { get; set; }
public int width { get; set; }
public int file_size { get; set; }
public string display_name { get; set; }
public int dpi { get; set; }
public string format { get; set; }
public bool is_licensable { get; set; }
}

public class MediumJpg
{
public int height { get; set; }
public int width { get; set; }
public int file_size { get; set; }
public string display_name { get; set; }
public int dpi { get; set; }
public string format { get; set; }
public bool is_licensable { get; set; }
}

public class HugeJpg
{
public int height { get; set; }
public int width { get; set; }
public int file_size { get; set; }
public string display_name { get; set; }
public int dpi { get; set; }
public string format { get; set; }
public bool is_licensable { get; set; }
}

public class SupersizeJpg
{
public int height { get; set; }
public int width { get; set; }
public int file_size { get; set; }
public string display_name { get; set; }
public int dpi { get; set; }
public string format { get; set; }
public bool is_licensable { get; set; }
}

public class HugeTiff
{
public int height { get; set; }
public int width { get; set; }
public int file_size { get; set; }
public string display_name { get; set; }
public int dpi { get; set; }
public string format { get; set; }
public bool is_licensable { get; set; }
}

 public class SupersizeTiff
{
public int height { get; set; }
public int width { get; set; }
public int file_size { get; set; }
public string display_name { get; set; }
public int dpi { get; set; }
public string format { get; set; }
public bool is_licensable { get; set; }
}

 public class VectorEps
 {
public int height { get; set; }
public int width { get; set; }
public int file_size { get; set; }
public string display_name { get; set; }
public int dpi { get; set; }
public string format { get; set; }
public bool is_licensable { get; set; }
}

public class SmallThumb
{
public string url { get; set; }
public int height { get; set; }
public int width { get; set; }
}

public class LargeThumb
{
public string url { get; set; }
public int height { get; set; }
public int width { get; set; }
}

public class Preview
{
public string url { get; set; }
public int height { get; set; }
public int width { get; set; }
}

public class Preview1000
{
public string url { get; set; }
public int height { get; set; }
public int width { get; set; }
}

public class Assets
{
public SmallJpg small_jpg { get; set; }
public MediumJpg medium_jpg { get; set; }
public HugeJpg huge_jpg { get; set; }
public SupersizeJpg supersize_jpg { get; set; }
public HugeTiff huge_tiff { get; set; }
public SupersizeTiff supersize_tiff { get; set; }
public VectorEps vector_eps { get; set; }
public SmallThumb small_thumb { get; set; }
public LargeThumb large_thumb { get; set; }
public Preview preview { get; set; }
public Preview1000 preview_1000 { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
public string id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
public string id { get; set; }
public string description { get; set; }
public string added_date { get; set; }
public string media_type { get; set; }
public Contributor contributor { get; set; }
public int aspect { get; set; }
public string image_type { get; set; }
public bool is_editorial { get; set; }
public bool is_adult { get; set; }
public bool is_illustration { get; set; }
public bool has_model_release { get; set; }
public bool has_property_release { get; set; }
public List<string> releases { get; set; }
public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
public List<string> keywords { get; set; }
public Assets assets { get; set; }
public List<Model> models { get; set; }
}
```

Use `Json.Net`

and you can deserialize json text into an object using following code

```
var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
var myojb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(objText);
```

For more information check [Serializing and Deserializing JSON with Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

Hope it helps.

Comment: and how do i create the object properties ?

Comment: try the above and all the value of properties of your model class will be stored in `MyObject` and when you will put a breakpoint , you will able to see all the values.

Comment: But when its come to this line ..I got the error directly that "Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array."

Comment: can you share value of `objText`?

Comment: Exactly the same as I post into my question when i use the `JSON` view

Comment: is there not any root tag in json like `DATA=your objText` ? If there would be root tag, it would become a lot easy. or else try replacing `RootObject` with `MyObject` in Sirwan's ans

Comment: getting error "Input string was not in a correct format." on the line `var myojb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(objText);`

Comment: check all the parameters datatype.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214402/unable-to-deserialize-the-json-result-in-c-input-string-is-not-in-a-correct-fo]